# Find the inflection points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to find the inflection points(i.e. $I_P(C,T_P C) \ge 3$) of cubic curve $x^3+y^3+z^3=0$ in $\mathbb{P}^2_k$

If $(char(k),2)=1$, I know that the smooth inflection points are equal to the intersection points with Hessian curve. Since the curve is smooth, we can find exactly all inflection points.

But how can I find them if $char(k)=2$?

Comment: @BabakSorouh Yes, I edited it.

Comment: You mean if $\text{char}(k) = 3$, right?

Comment: @MichaelJoyce No, I can find them in the case of $char(k)=3$ by computing some Hessian. But if $char(k)=2$, then I can't use Hessian and the only method I can do is using definition and direct computation, which seems hard.

Comment: Okay, but note that in $\text{char}(k) = 3$, your curve is simply the line $x + y + z = 0$ 'with scheme structure' because $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = (x + y + z)^3$ when $\text{char}(k) = 3$.  So it's really a 'triple line', which is singular at all points.

Comment: @MichaelJoyce I missed it, thanks!